# Why is ScrollView so hard to use in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I can't for the life of me make ScrollView behave like it should in my React-Native project. I know there are a ton of similar questions here, but none of the answers seem to work for me.

Code:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}} style={{}}>
        <ImageBackground
          style={signUpStyles.container}
          source={images.signUpBackground}>

          //content bigger than the screen

        </ImageBackground>
      </ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

```
//the style for ImageBackground
container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: '7%',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }
```

Things I've tried are:

- Move ScrollView around and use it as top container or lower level container
- use **{flexGrow: 1}** on contentContainerStyle
- use **{flex: 1}** on ScrollView style
- interchange and combine all of the above

The ScrollView doesn't let me scroll to the very bottom of the content, there is always content out of view.
I don't want to cheese it and add 'bumper' Views at the bottom in order to push everything up, as I am sure there has to be a real solution to this.

This is my first question here, so if I missed mentioning something please say it and I'll try to conform to everything.
Thank you for your time in advance!